# Identifying duplicate value within certain date using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I am trying to identify duplicate value

Condition:

1. Columns C & D both is matched
2. if condition 1 TRUE then Column I, date is  less than 30Days from the previous matched

then it will be marked as DUPLICATE

I am using below formula but second condition is not working. Even entries more than 30days older are also marked as duplicates.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,D:D,D2,I:I,"<="&I2)>1,COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,D:D,D2,I:I,">="&I2-30,I:I,"<="&I2+30)-1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide better data of what the desired result is. With your sample data just line 2 gets marked, which should be fine. And please provide it as markup data.

Comment: You mentioned Columns C &D, but the screenshot doesn't show the column names. Can you provide a better screenshot?

Comment: link of more clear and detail snapshot of excel https://imgur.com/a/tQIjfXj

Comment: Instead of + or - 30 you could look into EDATE `=EDATE(I2,-1)`